# What does equals to 2 means in this line fscanf (fi,"%d %d", &used,&quota)==2?

Tags: c, file, pointers

I started to learn files and I don't exactly understand how they are read.

1. My first question is: What does equals to 2 means in this line?

   ```
   fscanf(fi,"%d %d", &used,&quota) == 2
   ```

   Shouldn't it be equal to EOF, how will it understand that the program has reached the end?
2. How does the file with data in one line differs from the file with data in several lines. How does it read \n and how can I read only the first line or second for example?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the file with data in one line differs from the file with data in several lines. How does it read \n and how can I read only the first line or second for example?

This is another fun fact about the `scanf` family.  Given the call

```
fscanf(fi, "%d %d", &used, &quota)
```

and the input line

```
10 20
```

it will successfully read 10 for `used` and 20 for `quota`, which is probably what you had in mind.  But if you gave it the input

```
10
20
```

it would also perfectly happily read 10 for `used` and 20 for `quota`.  In fact it would work just as well for the input

```
10

20
```

with a blank line in there.  Furthermore, there's absolutely no way for you (that is, the author of the code that calls `fscanf`) to determine whether the input was on one line, or two lines, or what.

> Shouldn't it be equal to `EOF`, how will it understand that the program has reached the end?

It's true: if `fscanf` hits end of file before converting any input, it returns `EOF`, and that's something you might want to know about.  But that's not the only error condition you might want to know about.

Suppose the input line says

```
10 abc 20
```

In this case, the `fscanf` call will return 1, indicating that it was able to read the value 10 for `used`, but it wasn't able to read anything for `quota`.

The reason to check for 2 (as in the code you asked about ) is that only if `fscanf` returns 2 did it read and convert a value for *both* variables.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the manual page for `fscanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html):

> RETURN VALUE
>
> Upon successful completion, these functions shall **return the number
>          of successfully matched and assigned input items**; this number can be
>          zero in the event of an early matching failure.

So in this case, the check `fscanf(fi,"%d %d", &used,&quota) == 2` is to make sure that both `used` and `quota` were correctly read from the file.

---

> Shouldn't it be equal to EOF, how will it understand that the program has reached the end?

Well yes, only in that case though. Again, from the manual page:

> If the input ends
>          before the first conversion (if any) has completed, and without a
>          matching failure having occurred, EOF shall be returned.

---

> How does the file with data in one line differs from the file with data in several lines. How does it read \n and how can I read only the first line or second for example?

When you put a space (like here `"%d %d"`) in the format string, `fscanf` will skipp all whitespace it encounters (including spaces, `\n`, and other characters). This means that if you input `1 2` or `1      2` or `1\n2` all three inputs will be read with no problem.